# How to save python objects to sql database Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to save a python object to a database field using sql. I suppose it would be possible to create models that can save the individual attributes of that object, and I could write a method for reading from the database and creating the objects. I would prefer to not pursue that option because my object is very large and it would take a while to create all the fields for it.

Comment: If you do not want to filter the attributes in the object then I would look at using a BinaryField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield

Comment: Do you mean you want to save `json` representation of your object in a single column?

Comment: @alextford11 do you know the proper way of encoding the object into a byte-like object?

Comment: @Really_Bad_Coder No sorry, I have never used it, I just presume you use a BinaryField and all the hard work gets done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what DB and version of the DB you're using, I'd use a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField). The examples for insert and querying in the docs are great.